# Convergence $f^{k+1}(x)=f^k(x)\log(f^k(x))$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f^{k+1}(x)=f^k(x)\log(f^k(x))$ and $f^1(x)=\log x$.

What is $$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{xf^k(x)}$$ for $x\gg0$?

Comment: I did some TeX improvements, writing \log with a backslash, which not only de-italicizes it but also provides proper spacing between "log" and "x".  And I changed $x>>0$ to $x\gg 0$ (the TeX code is "x \gg 0").  But I stopped short of changing the superscripts to subscripts.  But subscripts would be more conventional and less likely to be confused with either of two other uses of superscripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will follow Michael's suggestion, and use lower indexes. Let's inspect few terms in the sequence $f_k(x)$:
$$
   f_1(x) = \log(x) \qquad f_2(x) = \log(x) \cdot \log(\log(x)) \qquad f_3(x)= \log(x) \cdot \log(\log(x)) \cdot \log(\log(\log(x)))
$$
Therefore $f_k(x) = \prod_{n=1}^k \log^{(\circ n)}(x)$. The sum, thus, has a form:
$$
   g(x) = \frac{1}{h_1} + \frac{1}{h_1 h_2} + \frac{1}{h_1 h_2 h_3} + \ldots = \frac{1}{h_1} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{h_2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{h_3} \left( 1+ \ldots \right)\right) \right)
$$
with $h_1(x) = x \log(x)$, $h_2(x) = \log(\log(x))$, $h_3(x) = \log(\log(\log(x)))$, and so on.

Thus
$$
   x \log(x) g(x) = h_1(x) g(x) = 1 + o(1)
$$
and thus for $x \gg 0$, $g(x) = O \left( \frac{1}{x \log(x)} \right)$.